# Trigger children's hover state when hovering the parent - Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent container with nested children. All of the children are being passed to the container and their count is unknown. Their type could be anything - headings, paragraphs, spans, divs etc. All of these children will have some predefined on hover state (the hover is defined outside of the parent scope, usually by the user who creates these elements) - change colours, backgrounds, text underline.

I'm looking for a way to triger the onhover state of all nested children elements when the parent element is being hovered. Is there a way to do this using JS and CSS ?

**Edit:** This is going to live in the realm of React with Styled Components

**Edit2:** Updated the demo code with a React example because the discussion went onto another direction.

Stressing on this part of the description:
*All of the children are being passed to the container and their count is unknown. Their type could be anything - headings, paragraphs, spans, divs etc. All of these children will have some predefined on hover state*

**Demo here:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bhabha-oh70d?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you can do it like this by having a hover on the `.box-main` element and calling the child element along with it.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box-main {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: grey;
  padding: 15px;
}

.box-main:hover h1{
  background: salmon;
}

.box-main:hover span{
  background: aqua;
}

.box-main:hover p{
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid temporibus minus odio nemo, aperiam asperiores, nostrum corrupti velit non illo saepe vero quisquam eius delectus optio dolor, quos architecto maiores.
  </div>
  <div class="box box-main">
    <h1>This is h1</h1>
    <span>Foloowed by span</span>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <div>lorem div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis, repudiandae quidem? Architecto ad omnis quos atque facilis fuga minus ipsa ab temporibus laudantium, ipsam est eos quia unde fugiat autem.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner what do you mean?

Comment: When you hover on the parent element, the background color of <div>lorem div</div> does not change. OP wrote "I'm looking for a way to triger the onhover state of **all nested children elements** when the parent element is being hovered".

Comment: If you are refering to the `.box` Lorem div which is not a child of `.box-main` then you will need to use this CSS code for that to work: `box-main:hover + .box{ background: lime;}`  Heres a jsfiddle of that: https://jsfiddle.net/ecsuakft/4/

Comment: No, I'm refering to **<div>lorem div</div>**.

Comment: That? well of course it wont do anything because there was no on hover state for that in OP's original post. So I never styled anything for that div.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't correspond to the question. Maybe OP should clear that.

Comment: Oh it seems OP updated his question. It was different before. It is not possible to do what he wants.

Comment: Anyway, I like your solution. I've just upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the cascading nature of style in this case, hover on the parent will also trigger hover on the upper parents so with `css` you can add hover pseudo selector on the `.box` class :

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.box-main {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: grey;
  padding: 15px;
}
.box:hover > h1 {
   background: salmon;
}

.box:hover span {
  background: aqua;
}
.box:hover p{
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid temporibus minus odio nemo, aperiam asperiores, nostrum corrupti velit non illo saepe vero quisquam eius delectus optio dolor, quos architecto maiores.
  </div>
  <div class="box box-main">
    <h1>This is h1</h1>
    <span>Foloowed by span</span>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <div>lorem div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis, repudiandae quidem? Architecto ad omnis quos atque facilis fuga minus ipsa ab temporibus laudantium, ipsam est eos quia unde fugiat autem.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add another class for all the other elements with for ex: `.box:hover > * { background: blue;  }`